# Execute bulk find queries with sorting and limit mongo

Tags: performance, mongodb

I have documents that contain a category field and I want to take the top 10 documents from each category based on popularity, seniority and rise in popularity. I plan on using a `votes` field within the document to determine the popularity, the `_id` field for seniority and a `votesPerDay` field to determine which are rising in popularity. There are a total of 12 categories.

Typical documents will look like this.

```
{
   name : 'alpaca',
   category : 'blue',
   votes : 500,
   _id : Object.Id,
   votesPerDay : 50
}

{
   name : 'muon',
   category : 'green',
   votes : 100,
   _id : Object.Id,
   votesPerDay : 20
}
```

I have an object that needs to store all the categories and within each category it will store the most popular, the newest and those rising in popularity. The object will be refreshed every 24 hours.

Where I am running into trouble is whenever I want to query mongo for all 12 different categories.

I have tried to have a for loop run three queries for each category and store the results once they arrive but this fails since it seems that I am over loading mongo server and it crashes.

the architecture of the object I am trying to build will look something like this.

```
var myObj = {category1 : { 
   newest : [0,2....9],
   mostPopular : [0,2....9],
   risingInPopularity : [0,2....9]

} ..... with 12 of such objects};
```

the way I initially thought of performing the queries (although I am a bit uncomfortable doing it this way) was.

```
categories.forEach(function(category){


    var query = {category : category}
    var sort = //sorting criterion for newest

    performQuery(query,sorting,function(results){

      myObject[category].newest = results

    });

    sort = //sorting criterion for most popular

performQuery(query,sorting,function(results){

      myObject[category].mostPopular= results

    });


sort = //sorting criterion for rising in popularity

performQuery(query,sorting,function(results){

      myObject[category].risingInPopularity = results

    });


//limit has to be set to 10 documents


});
```

So my question is how is it best to perform this type of mass query where I will need to obtain documents based on category and retrieve only those top 10 documents that have the most votes, are the most recently added (based on `_id`), and have the most `votesPerDay`.

Comment: Bulk Operations are for updating or inserting documents and not for simply issuing queries. Your question is very unclear as to what the document content looks like and what operations you actually need to do. Sample documents and an expected result usually help to add clarity to the question that you are asking.

Comment: I have tried to clarify my question by adding more information, hopefully it is understandable now. Thanks.

Comment: There are still lots of problems here. 1. "12 categories", so forget names like "blue" and "green" and just call them 1..12 for the sake of the question or at least make it clear which field is grouped ( we presume category ). 2. Objects basically have category, votes, votes per day. But based on what? Are these already aggregated values? With what frequency? Are they real or just proposed? No dates are included other than the worst possible `ObjectId` value. Working out "recentlyAdded" and "mostPopular" how? 3. Your psuedocode does not address any of this. This looks more like a proposal.

Comment: Therefore. Try to explain the real problem. If you don't yet have a data structure then think in terms of what you need to collect to get to the results. What is listed here cannot possibly come out to the "popular", "reccent" or "trending" statistics you want.

Comment: Well truthfully all of that information is of little importance, I was just trying to give some context. What my question really boils down to is how can I run 36 simultaneous queries that retrieve a total of 360 documents without overloading mongo.

Comment: is there perhaps a bulk find function? or a specific way to query the db without overloading it.

Comment: You have already been told no. And I have also told you that is is not possible to determine the metrics you want from the data you have recorded. You might learn to take some advice as your further commentary has not really clarified or added anything of value, which is what it is meant to do here.